# Kadison's transitivity theorem application in a proof (Murphy's $"C^*$-algebras and operator theory")

Tags: proof-explanation, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Excuse the long post, I just wanted to make the post self-contained so that those who don't have Murphy's book can also understand my question. Consider the following fragment in Murphy's book (p161):

[image]

Why is there a unitary $u$ in the unitisation $\tilde{A}$ with $\varphi(u)x = x_\rho$? Since we have an irreducible representation $(H_\rho, \varphi)$ of $\tilde{A}$, we know that $\varphi(\tilde{A})$ acts irreducibly on $H_\rho$. Since $x$ and $x_\rho$ are unit vectors, there is a unitary in $B(H_\rho)$ that takes $x$ to $x_\rho$, so by Kadison's transitivity theorem there is a unitary $\varphi(u) \in \varphi(\tilde{A})$ with $\varphi(u)x = x_\rho$. However, the book claims that we can choose $u$ to be a unitary in $A$. How can we ensure this? Is maybe the following true?

Let $(H, \varphi)$ be an irreducible representation of a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$. If $\varphi(a)$ is a unitary in $\varphi(A)$, then $a$ is a unitary in $A$?

I don't think this holds, but we do know $uu^*-u^*u \in \ker(\varphi)$

Comment: Take the unitary in $\phi(A)$ of the form $e^{iw}$, with $w$ self-adjoint, lift $w$ to a self-adjoint element $z$ in $A$ and consider $u=e^{iz}$.

Comment: @Ruy Please make this an answer with more details! Thanks! I will put a bounty on it once I can.

Comment: Done.  But I guess your understanding of the term "bounty" is not what it should be.

Comment: It is. You'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the OP, using Kadison's transitivity Theorem, one can find a unitary operator $v$ (called  $\varphi(u)$
in the OP) in $\varphi(\tilde{A})$  with $vx = x_\rho$.  By the very last sentence of KTT one may actually suppose that $v=e^{iw}$, for some
self-adjoint operator $w$ in $\varphi(\tilde{A})$.

Next pick $z$ in $\tilde A$ such that $\varphi(z)=w$ and immediately
replace it by $(z+z^*)/2$, so that the new $z$ is self-adjoint and still satisfies $\varphi(z)=w$. Finally set $u=e^{iz}$.

One then has that $u$ is unitary and
$$
  \varphi(u) =
  \varphi(e^{iz}) =
  e^{i\varphi(z)} =
  e^{iw} = v.
  $$